# Converting my application from titanium to ionic and upload to store

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play, titanium

I have an application that was originally built in titanium and I have now update the app in ionic platform. The problem is that when I try to upload my update on google play store I get this error:

```
Upload failed
Your APK has been signed with multiple certificates. Please only sign it with one certificate and upload it again.
You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. 
Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):
[ SHA1: CC:E3:7F:08:FA:03:9C:88:07:BC:CB:AB:7B:88:61:F4:75:9D:47:9F ]
and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):
[ SHA1: 20:9F:16:C0:05:AC:8E:04:C8:B0:D9:A7:AA:40:17:46:FB:1B:1F:7B],
[ SHA1: BB:D7:DC:34:B9:03:73:EA:40:C4:42:B2:01:17:05:EB:75:14:40:4D ]
```

[Google Play Store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYrDR.png)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you're signing the new Apk with a keystore different than the one used to sign the old Apps. To solve this you need to sign your Apk with the same keystore used before.

Comment: yes thanks i know that but where can i find mine as i was using titanium studio 4 [link](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Packaging_Titanium_Applications-section-37524722_PackagingTitaniumApplications-Android)